# Classifying vertex-transitive dihedral graphs

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Is there some way to generate adjacency matrices for all graphs with $n$ vertices that have a dihedral $D_{n}$ symmetry which acts transitively on the vertices? (the vertex set cardinality $n$ being the same as the $n$ in the $D_{n}$ subscript) For example for circulant graphs, each row of the adjacency matrix will be a cyclic permutation of the previous row. Is there some more general procedure?

Comment: Do you need to generate all possible adjacency matrices, or is it enough to have at least one adjacency matrix for each isomorphism class of graphs? (Note: It is possible to have an adjacency matrix for a circulant graph which does not have the form you describe, depending on how the vertices are ordered.)

Comment: Look up ‘Cayley graph’.

Comment: Which notation are you using for dihedral groups? Does $D_n$ have order $n$ or $2n$?